# How to setup MySQL source code in Xcode?

Tags: mysql, xcode, sdk, open-source

I would like to setup MySQL source 5.7 code in Xcode so that I can start investigating the source code. Ideally I would like to be able to compile and run MySQL from Xcode so that I can use the Xcode debugger to step through the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the steps which helps you to debug MySQL in Xcode

http://technicalqueriess.blogspot.in/2016/04/1-donwload-mysql5.html

Comment: Link-only answers should be posted as comments.